# How to write on_change query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to execute an on-change event . There is one drop down and one lock button so when i select name from that drop down it should lock an issue to that selected name .

```
<td>
   <% if issue_request.status == true %>
      <small class="btn btn-sm btn-success fa fa-check"></small>
   <% else %>
     <% if issue_request.issue_tracker_member_id == nil %>
        <%= select :issue_request,:issue_tracker_member_id,issue_tracker_member_role_wise(issue_request.issue_tracker_group.id),{prompt:"Select Member"},class: "form-control"%>
                          <%= link_to '',lock_request_issue_requests_path(issue_request),class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-lock',data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> 
                        <% else %>
                          <small class="label label-primary">Locked by <%= current_user.employee.try(:manual_employee_code) %></small>

                              <%= link_to '',unlock_request_issue_requests_path(issue_request),class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning fa fa-unlock-alt',data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> | <%= link_to 'Solved',solved_request_issue_requests_path(issue_request),class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                               <% end %> 
                        <% end %> 
                    </td>
                  <% end %>
              </tr>
            <% end %> 
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: check this..http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp ...to learn and understand the basics of jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can write an onchange event in java script or jquery to get it done. You will need to use the script tags and mention javascript in it. If you are using an external js file then you need to create it under the assets directory in the app.

Comment: I don't know how to write jquery can you please help me .

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your view file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.form-control').on('change',function(){
        $('fa-unlock-alt').prop('disabled', true);
      })
    }
 </script>
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: again not working . Do u need more information to write code ?

Comment: which type of issue facing.please show me your errors logs

Comment: you select any value from `issue_request` then after issue_request lock or click on button then after lock select which one you need.